# Get MIME Type of Multimedia Types based on file extension using TOM.NET (.NET Templating)

Tags: web8.5, templating, tom.net, c#

> Recently I recevied client business requirement to get MIME Type of  Multimedia
>   Types item based on extension (External Url) from Tridion using C# Templating.
>
> - Read all Multimedia Types from Tridion.
> - Check Tridion Multimedia Types File Extensions with Input Extension.
> - If it`s match Multimedia Type
> - Take the MIME Type of Multimedia Type.
> - No Hard code  Multimedia Type and MIME Type in C# Template code.

https://domain.com/audio/test/test_20191010.mp3  - Result  (MIME Type : audio/x-mpeg)
https://domain.com/video/test/test_20191002.mpg  - Result (MIME Type : video/mpeg).

Looking for Ideas and Solution for above requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final I got solution MimeType based on file extension and code below.

```
> // @ExternalUrlTridionFields - Tridion ExternalUrl Field Name //
> Engine engine string FileExtension = string.Empty; string mimeType =
> string.Empty; if (Path.HasExtension(@ExternalUrlTridionFields))   //
> Checking URL Extension {
>     FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(@ExternalUrlFields);   // Get Url Extension 
>     string InputExt = FileExtension.StartsWith(".") ? FileExtension.Substring(1) : FileExtension;  // Removing dot from the
> URL File Extension (.mp3)
>     var multimediaTypes = engine.GetSession().SystemManager.GetMultimediaTypes() ;  // Read All
> Tridion MultimediaTypes  
>         foreach (var mmType in multimediaTypes)
>         {
>             List<string> FileExtensions = mmType.FileExtensions.ToList(); // Multiple multimediaTypes Extension
> in signal item
>             if (FileExtensions.Contains(InputExt))   // Checking multimediaTypes extension Contains with input extension.
>             {                                                         
>                 foreach (string FileExtension in FileExtensions)
>                 {
>                     if(FileExtension.Equals(InputExt))   // Checking multimediaType extension equal with input extension.
>                     {                                       
>                       mimeType = mmType.MimeType;  // Read multimediaType MimeType
>                     }                                                                   
>                 }
>             }
>         }              
>                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Multimedia Types include one or more file or mime types. I don't see why you need to rely on the Multimedia Type definitions for the mime types. I guess you might try to use Tridion to manage this list of mime types to extension, but I doubt they're available (at the granularity you need) over TOM.NET. Check the documentation to be sure.

If you really want to avoid hard-coding these values I'm thinking you could either inspect the mime type directly from the external item or configure these outside of your template code in a Component or some metadata.

I would just be careful that the file's actual mime type may not necessarily match the file extension.